# How can I see which kubernetes user is creating the deployment and what type of authentication is used?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to see which kubernetes user is creating the deployment and what type of authentication is used (basic auth, token, etc).
I try to do it using this:

```
kubectl describe deployment/my-workermole
```

but I am not finding that type of information in there.
Cluster is not managed by me and I am not able to find it in the deployment Jenkinsfile. Where and how can I find that type of information in my kubernetes deployment but after deployment?

Comment: Check with the cluster admin if the [auditing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/) has been enabled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes: need notification if a new namespace is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69317847/kubernetes-need-notification-if-a-new-namespace-is-created)

Comment: @P.... Unfortunately not directly, I need to dig through answers and I see that the audit has among other the who created information but not authentication type and the example is for name spaces and not deployments, but in a sense I have a small hint that I need to work with auditing...

Comment: yes, its not a direct answer. Hope it helped you to get the right direction. Also, you may need to play around with with the level of the loggings like metadata, requestreceived etc.Anyway , authorization type may not be captured in this...but worth checking.

Comment: @P.... worth checking, thanks, but definitely not a duplicate question

Comment: yes, retracted the vote

Comment: Does "[Kubernetes auditing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/)" meet your requirements ?
Do you have Kubernetes on bare-metal or Managed Kubernetes Service ?

Comment: @matt_j  Managed Kubernetes Service, auditing seems what I need but I don't know at the moment how to approach it

Comment: Thank you for all the information you provided. I would like to ask two more questions.
Which Managed Kubernetes Service are you using ?
What version of Kubernetes do you have ?